# How to remove bricks on collision?

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics, mathematics, swing

I am on my last stage of creating a simple breakout game in Java using BlueJ. I have added multiple rows of bricks using an `ArrayList`. However now the task is to remove the bricks upon being hit by the ball. I currently have a for loop in my Model class, but it seems to pass through the first few rows and then only collide with bricks around the middle. Here is the loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 60; i++ ){
    GameObj brick1 = bricks.get(i);

    if ( brick1.hitBy(ball) ){
        bricks.remove(i);
        ball.changeDirectionY();
        addToScore(50); 

    }
}
```

When i change the i <= 60 it seems to start to hit the bricks within the lower rows but still it isn't working properly. Here is the full code for the class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;

/**
* Model of the game of breakout
* @author Mike Smith University of Brighton
*/

public class Model extends Observable
{
// Boarder
private static final int B              = 6;  // Border offset
private static final int M              = 40; // Menu offset

// Size of things
private static final float BALL_SIZE    = 18; // Ball side
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH  = 48; // Brick size
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 20;
private static final float BAT_WIDTH  = 50; 
private static final float BAT_HEIGHT = 30;

private static final int BAT_MOVE       = 5; // Distance to move bat

// Scores
private static final int HIT_BRICK      = 50;  // Score
private static final int HIT_BOTTOM     = -200;// Score

private GameObj ball;          // The ball
private ArrayList<GameObj> bricks;  // The bricks
private GameObj bat;           // The bat

private boolean runGame = true; // Game running
private boolean fast = false;   // Sleep in run loop

private int score = 0;

private final int W ;       // Width of area
private final float H;         // Height of area

private static final int BRICK_SEP = 4;
private static final int BRICK_Y_OFFSET = 100;
private static final int BRICK_X_OFFSET = 42;
private static final int NBRICKS_PER_ROW = 10;
private static final int NBRICK_ROWS = 2;
// Height of area

public Model( int width, int height )
{
    this.W = width; this.H = height;
}

/**
 * Create in the model the objects that form the game
 */

public void createGameObjects()
{
    synchronized( Model.class )
    {
        ball   = new GameObj(W/2, H/2, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE, Colour.RED);
        bat    = new GameObj(W/2, H - BAT_HEIGHT*1.5f, BAT_WIDTH*3, 
            BAT_HEIGHT/4, Colour.WHITE);
        bricks = new ArrayList<>();
        // *[1]******************************************************[1]*
        // * Fill in code to place the bricks on the board              *
        // **************************************************************/

        // pink first 2 rows
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
            int y = BRICK_Y_OFFSET + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

            for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
                int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
                bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.PINK));
            }
        }
        // blue second 2 rows // math = 4 + 20 * 2 = 48 
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
            int y = (BRICK_Y_OFFSET+48) + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

            for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
                int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
                bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.BLUE) );
            }
        }
        // orange third 2 rows // math = 48 + 48 = 96
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
            int y = (BRICK_Y_OFFSET+96) + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

            for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
                int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
                bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.GREEN) );
            }
        }
        // green fourth 2 rows // math = 96 + 48 = 144
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
            int y = (BRICK_Y_OFFSET+144) + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

            for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
                int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
                bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.ORANGE) );
            }
        }
        // cyan fith 2 rows // math = 144 + 48 = 192
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
        int y = (BRICK_Y_OFFSET+192) + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

        for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
        int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
        bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.CYAN ));
        }
        }
        //magenta sixth 2 rows // math = 192 + 48 
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
        int y = (BRICK_Y_OFFSET+240) + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

        for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
        int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
        bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.MAGENTA ));
        }
        }

        //yellow seventh 2 rows // math = 240 + 48 
         for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++){
        int y = (BRICK_Y_OFFSET+288) + (i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP));

        for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++){
        int x = (BRICK_X_OFFSET) + (j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP));
        bricks.add(new GameObj (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Colour.YELLOW ));
        }
        }



        }  

    } 


private ActivePart active  = null;
/**
 * Start the continuous updates to the game
 */
public void startGame()
{
    synchronized ( Model.class )
    {
        stopGame();
        active = new ActivePart();
        Thread t = new Thread( active::runAsSeparateThread );
        t.setDaemon(true);   // So may die when program exits
        t.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop the continuous updates to the game
 * Will freeze the game, and let the thread die.
 */
public void stopGame()
{  
    synchronized ( Model.class )
    {
        if ( active != null ) { active.stop(); active = null; }
    }
}

public GameObj getBat()             { return bat; }

public GameObj getBall()            { return ball; }

public ArrayList<GameObj> getBricks()    { return bricks; }

/**
 * Add to score n units
 * @param n units to add to score
 */
protected void addToScore(int n)    { score += n; }

public int getScore()               { return score; }

/**
 * Set speed of ball to be fast (true/ false)
 * @param fast Set to true if require fast moving ball
 */
public void setFast(boolean fast)   
{ 
    this.fast = fast; 
}

/**
 * Move the bat. (-1) is left or (+1) is right
 * @param direction - The direction to move
 */
public void moveBat( int direction )
{
    // *[2]******************************************************[2]*
    // * Fill in code to prevent the bat being moved off the screen *
    // **************************************************************    

    float dist = direction * BAT_MOVE;    // Actual distance to movefinal 
    float MIN_X = 10; 
    final float MAX_X = 440; 

    if(dist > 0 && bat.getX() < MAX_X) 
    { 
        bat.moveX(dist); 
    } 
    else if ( dist < 0 && bat.getX() > MIN_X) 
    { 
        bat.moveX(dist); 
    } 

    Debug.trace( "Model: Move bat = %6.2f", dist );

}

/**
 * This method is run in a separate thread
 * Consequence: Potential concurrent access to shared variables in the class
 */
class ActivePart
{
    private boolean runGame = true;

    public void stop()
    {
        runGame = false;
    }

    public void runAsSeparateThread()
    {
        final float S = 3; // Units to move (Speed) 
        try
        {
            synchronized ( Model.class ) // Make thread safe 
            {
                GameObj       ball   = getBall();     // Ball in game 
                GameObj       bat    = getBat();      // Bat 
                ArrayList<GameObj> bricks = getBricks();   // Bricks 
            }

            while (runGame)
            {
                synchronized ( Model.class ) // Make thread safe 
                {
                    float x = ball.getX();  // Current x,y position 
                    float y = ball.getY();
                    // Deal with possible edge of board hit 
                    if (x >= W - B - BALL_SIZE)  ball.changeDirectionX();
                    if (x <= 0 + B            )  ball.changeDirectionX();
                    if (y >= H - B - BALL_SIZE)  // Bottom 
                    { 
                        ball.changeDirectionY(); addToScore( HIT_BOTTOM ); 
                    }
                    if (y <= 0 + M            )  ball.changeDirectionY();

                    // As only a hit on the bat/ball is detected it is  
                    //  assumed to be on the top or bottom of the object. 
                    // A hit on the left or right of the object 
                    //  has an interesting affect 

                    boolean hit = false;
                    // *[3]******************************************************[3]* 
                    // * Fill in code to check if a visible brick has been hit      * 
                    // *      The ball has no effect on an invisible brick          * 
                    // ************************************************************** 

                    /* if( // ball Y pos < brick Y pos = collision )
                    {
                    brick = null;
                    }
                    for ( int i = 0; i <= 60; i++ ){
                    GameObj brick1 = bricks.get(i);

                    if ( y <= brick1.getY() - (BRICK_HEIGHT/2)){

                    bricks.set(i, null); // The brick in the position of i when the ball collides, will be null

                    hit = true;
                    Debug.trace("BreakOut");

                    }
                    List<GameObj> toRemove = new ArrayList<GameObj>();
                    for(GameObj a: bricks){
                    if(a.getY() <= brick1.getY() - (BRICK_HEIGHT/2)){
                    toRemove.add(a);
                    }
                    }
                    bricks.removeAll(toRemove); */

                    for ( int i = 0; i <= 60; i++ ){
                        GameObj brick1 = bricks.get(i);

                        if ( brick1.hitBy(ball) ){
                            bricks.remove(i);
                            //hit = true;
                            ball.changeDirectionY();

                            //ball.changeDirectionX();
                            addToScore(50); 

                        }
                    } 


                    if (hit)
                        ball.changeDirectionY();

                    if ( ball.hitBy(bat) )
                        ball.changeDirectionY();
                } 
                modelChanged();      // Model changed refresh screen 
                Thread.sleep( fast ? 2 : 20 );
                ball.moveX(S);  ball.moveY(S);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Debug.error("Model.runAsSeparateThread - Error\n%s", 
                e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Model has changed so notify observers so that they
 *  can redraw the current state of the game
 */
public void modelChanged()
{
    setChanged(); notifyObservers();
}



}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through *all* of the bricks, not just the first 60. You also should be careful about remove items from a container while iterating over it. I use the "remove list" idiom myself a lot. So you're code should look something like the following (pseudocode):

```
ArrayList removeList = new ArrayList()
for (int i = 0; i < bricks.length(); i++) 
{
    GameObj brick = bricks[i]
    if (brick.hitBy(ball)) 
    {
        removeList.add(brick)
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < removeList.length(); i++)
{
    GameObj toRemove = removeList[i];
    bricks.remove(toRemove)

    // etc: bounce ball, add score, whatever.
}
```

Comment: yes sorry shouldve had 160 instead of 60 and new this is what seemed to be the problem but when i put the correct number of bricks in it returned just a blank white screen. I will look at this code and see if it works. Thankyou

Comment: Kinda sounds like you have an issue in `hitBy` then.

Comment: Im getting a few error messages such as 'cannot find symbol method length' and 'array required but Java.Util.ArrayList found'

Comment: I gave you pseudocode, not Java that compiles.

Comment: do you know how i would go about trying to make it work using an arraylist then

Comment: Googling "arraylist get length" seems to indicate that `bricks.size()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: yes thankyou was just about to comment i found it

Comment: giving me the error message GameObj cannot be converted to int now

Comment: Are you properly giving `removeList` a type? (`ArrayList<GameObj>`)

Comment: ArrayList removeList = new ArrayList<GameObj>(); like this?

Comment: Probably `ArrayList<GameObj> removeList = new ArrayList<GameObj>()`. These are anyways quite trivial implementation details that you should be able to figure out.

Comment: Yes i had that originally, bricks.size(); still says incompatible types and so does removeList.size();

Comment: Mmm this is why I gave you pseudocode, I don't know the Java details. ArrayList can't be indexed, so you need to replace the `[i]` sections with `get(i)`.

Comment: this seems to be working fine, just need to add the collision between ball and brick then it should be perfect i think

Comment: added the collision and works perfectly. Thanks a lot mate!! Great help

Comment: Glad I could help and good luck with the project!